# ¿Como limitar la suma de registros a una columna hasta un valor X?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo dos tablas:

1. **Clientes**: Guardar datos de los clientes, tales como: ID, Nombre, **Puntos**.
2. **Ventas**: Registra las ventas hechas por cada cliente, así:ID_Clientes, Servicio (**10 minutos por ejemplo**), entre otros.

Deseo entonces que en el campo **Puntos** de la tabla **Clientes** se registren los servicios hasta cuando llegue a X cantidad, si supera esa cantidad (por ejemplo 90) lo actualiza a Cero para la próxima venta.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento? ¿Con qué problemas te estás encontrando? Por favor, añade el código relevante que lleves hasta ahora.

Comment: Como ha dicho @AlvaroMontoro Es necesario que des más precisión sobre lo que quieres lograr y lo que has intentando. Por ejemplo, me pregunto ¿qué pasa con los puntos que borras, se pierden sin más sustituyéndolos por un nuevo conteo? Si es eso. Tendrías a)`SELECT` a la tabla clientes preguntando por el valor actual de la columna en cuestión y b)Un `UPDATE` sometido a dos condiciones: b1. Si el valor de la columna=90 lo sustituyes por el valor que iría en el `UPDATE` b2. Si <>90  sumas el valor obtenido en (a) con el valor nuevo y haces el `UPDATE`. Esa sería más o menos la lógica.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de tus tablas fuente y de cómo esperarías que fuese la salida. Tu descripción cuesta imaginársela así sin más

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function bonus_data($data)
{

date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
$t = $data["params"]["reference_no"];
$client_id = $data["params"]["customer_id"];
$venta = $data["params"]["sale_status"];

global $h;
$res = $h->execute_query("select id, name, company, award_points from sma_companies WHERE id = '$client_id'");
#phpgrid_error($h->con->errormsg());
$arr = $res->GetRows();
#phpgrid_error($arr);
$puntos = $arr[0]["award_points"];
$nombre_cliente = $arr[0]["company"];
$documento = $arr[0]["name"];

if($venta == 'Bono'){
$acu = $puntos - 180;
    $h->execute_query("UPDATE sma_companies SET award_points = '$acu' WHERE id = '$client_id'");
} else {
    $acu = $puntos + $t;
    $h->execute_query("UPDATE sma_companies SET award_points = '$acu' WHERE id = '$client_id'");
}
}
```

Comment: Hola @c3media, aunque tu respuesta sea buena, deberías al menos hacer comentarios explicando lo que hace tu código.

Answer (score -1):

esta es mi función:

```
function bonus_data($data)
{
    $t = $data["params"]["reference_no"];
    $client_id = $data["params"]["customer_id"];
    global $h;
    $h->execute_query("select award_points from sma_companies WHERE id = '$client_id'");
    $puntos = $h;

if ($puntos < "180") {
    $t=$data["params"]["reference_no"];
    global $h;
    $h->execute_query("UPDATE sma_companies SET award_points = '$t' + '$puntos' WHERE id = '$client_id'");
    } 
    else 
    if ($puntos > "180")
    {
    $t=$data["params"]["reference_no"];
    global $h;
    $h->execute_query("UPDATE sma_companies SET award_points = '$t' WHERE id = '$client_id'");
}
}
```

El problema está en que solo me actualiza al insertar el registro (puntos), pero no me está realizando la consulta del último registro (puntos) para acumularlo con el actual.

Gracias por su ayuda al respecto!

Comment: Tema resuelto amigos!